# PostgreSQL Check if security_invoker is turned on on view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

Since PostgreSQL 15 it is possible to set `security_invoker` on views. I was wondering how to check if my views have it enabled or not, as neither pgAdmin nor DataGrip doesn't show that.

Comment: Are you using the latest pgAdmin? It is a fairly new feature.

Comment: Yes, version 6.21. Do you know if it is actually possible to see it there somewhere?

Comment: I just checked, and support for that is really missing. I'd call that a bug, because it shows the view definition incorrectly. You should report that to pgAdmin.

Comment: I've created an new issue for pgAdmin on Github: https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/6099

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to check all views in the `public` schema:

```sql
select 
  relname, 
  case 
    when lower(reloptions::text)::text[] && array['security_invoker=1','security_invoker=true','security_invoker=on'] 
      then true else false
  end as security_invoker
from pg_class
  join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
where n.nspname = 'public' and relkind='v';
```

In the internal `pg_class` table there is a column called `reloptions` which knows if the `security_invoker` is turned on.

Example output for `reloptions`: `{security_invoker=true}` and `{security_invoker=on}` or is `null` by default if it isn't turned on.